# Google Bigquery - Iterator has already started

Tags: python, google-bigquery, iterator

Getting the error "Iterator already started" when using the results of a Bigquery with Python and would appreciate some help.

```
query_job_doi = client.query(config_doi_sql).result()
query_job_articles = client.query(topic_articles_sql).result()


for row in query_job_doi:
   for row_a in query_job_articles:
      if row[0]==row_a[0]:
        print("Success")
      else:
        print("DOI Miss match")
```

While running the code in the VM instance, it's giving the error -

`('Iterator has already started', <google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator object at 0x7fd82fe88150>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
query_job_doi = list(client.query(config_doi_sql).result())
query_job_articles = list(client.query(topic_articles_sql).result())

for row in query_job_doi:
   for row_a in query_job_articles:
      if row[0]==row_a[0]:
        print("Success")
      else:
        print("DOI Miss match")
```